# Win Vista/7 File info direct from right click context menu

Tags: windows, file, contextmenu

I’m fairly up to date with creating a context menu and using vbs files to obtain information on files.  What I’m looking to do is to get information directly when I right click a file – say for example that files attributes.  Now I know that I just have to click on Properties to see that but I’m looking to have such information displayed with a single right click.  Can this be done?  If so could someone give me some pointers to achieving this.
Thanks.

Comment: Right click on a file on Windows Explorer only displays the context menu for the file. At most, you could create a menu with shell extension with text variable based on attributes of the file. I doubt how useful is going to be this.

Comment: I would add that the built-in details pane shows some information on the selected file, and extensions like classic shell also fix the status bar so that it displays useful information, all this with only selecting files.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro.  I already have a 'File Status' option on the context menu that gives me quite a bit of information about the file.  Mainly, I was looking to see whether the file I had right-clicked was read only or not without further clicks.